# transform only subarray of objects in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to transform this JSON object:

```
{
  "id_1": {},
  "id_2": {
    "sys": "S",
    "details": [
      {
        "detail": "S1",
        "index": 0
      },
      {
        "detail": " ",
        "index": 1
      },
      {
        "detail": " ",
        "index": 2
      },
      {
        "detail": " ",
        "index": 3
      },
      {
        "detail": " ",
        "index": 4
      }
    ],
    "color": "Grey"
  },
  "id_3": {
    "sys": "A",
    "details": [
      {
        "detail": "240",
        "index": 0
      },
      {
        "detail": "63",
        "index": 1
      },
      {
        "detail": "70",
        "index": 2
      },
      {
        "detail": " ",
        "index": 3
      },
      {
        "detail": " ",
        "index": 4
      }
    ],
    "color": "White"
  },
  "id_4": {},
  "id_5": {
    "sys": "G",
    "details": [
      {
        "detail": "266",
        "index": 0
      },
      {
        "detail": "G",
        "index": 1
      },
      { 
        "detail": "1",
        "index": 2
      },
      {
        "detail": " ",
        "index": 3
      },
      {
        "detail": " ",
        "index": 4
      } 
    ],
    "color": "Red"
  }     
}
```

into that one:

```
{
  "id_1": {},
  "id_2": {
    "sys": "S",
    "details": ["S1"],
    "color": "Grey",
  },
  "id_3": {
    "sys": "A",
    "details": ["240","63","70"],
    "color": "White",
  },
  "id_4": {},
  "id_5": {
    "sys": "G",
    "details": ["266", "G", "1"],
    "color": "Red",
  }
}
```

There are also empty objects in the outer object that should be remained. Only the key `details` should be transformed, others should be kept.

Could not achive to create any valid query with `map` nor with `select`. The only valid `jq` I have created so far: `.[]? | [.details[]? | select(.detail != " ")] | .[] .detail`, but only results the details strings...

Comment: What is "big" JSON in this context? as in millons of objects or only a few?

Comment: No, not millions, only 144 ;) I've used "big" because its a "bigger" dict containing dicts instead of a list of dicts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
map_values(
  select(has("details")) .details |=
    map(.detail | select(. != " "))
)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FLZn2yceimc)</sup>

Comment: Works as asked :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `values` to empty objects not having a `.details` field (or having one with `null` as its value).

```bash
.[].details |= (values | map(.detail | select(. != " ")))
```

```json
{
  "id_1": {},
  "id_2": {
    "sys": "S",
    "details": ["S1"],
    "color": "Grey"
  },
  "id_3": {
    "sys": "A",
    "details": ["240", "63", "70"],
    "color": "White"
  },
  "id_4": {},
  "id_5": {
    "sys": "G",
    "details": ["266", "G", "1"],
    "color": "Red"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rtDnjQ9a0X7)

Comment: @Chris `values` is a [shortcut](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L63) for `select(. != null)`, and accessing non-existent fields evaluates to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
jq 'map_values(.details? |= map(select(.detail != " "))' file.json
```

Comment: Filter does not work for me: syntax error.